# Is it a free action for a monster to release a grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, grapple

Here's the scenario that elicited this question.

A Roc swoops in and lands a Talon attack, which grapples the target on hit. Roc flies up with remaining movement and then, as a free action, releases the grapple, causing the target to fall.

It's the free action here I am asking about. Would the Roc still have action economy left to release the grapple or would it have to wait for it's next turn?

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before. (This is okay, duplicates can help others find the questions they're looking for.)